# Storing objects in an array for retirevel and modification of instantiated objects (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, polymorphism

Hello I am new to Java and taking this course in my college studies. This assignment I am doing is all about polymorphism, and we are suppose to make 4 objects: 2 without arguments, and 2 with arguments.

```
PersonLocation personLocation = new PersonLocation();
PersonData personData = new PersonData();

PersonLocation personLocationOverloaded = new PersonLocation("Hamilton");
PersonData personDataOverloaded = new PersonData("Frizzle", "289-549-1045");
```

Now I am fairly sure I did this properly, but the next part is were I am confused. It asks to "store all the objects in an array for retrieval and modification of instantiated objects". But I am not sure how to go about this. I was thinking:

```
PersonLocation[] personLocation = new PersonLocation[4];
PersonData[] personData = new PersonData[4];
```

But this doesn't make any sense because now I would have 8 objects. I thought of putting them together:

```
String[] employees = new String[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    employees[i] = personLocation;
}

for(int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
{
    employees[i] = personData;
}
```

This seems like it would make more sense because I have a superClass of `Location` and a subClass of `Data`.

Any pointers in the right direction for creating an array of objects for retrieval and modification of instantiated objects would be of great help.

Comment: In Java, there is a root class called `Object` from which every other class is inherited. So if you go up the inheritance tree from the two classes of yours, you are going to find a common ancestor class, not necessarily the Object class.

Comment: I'm just speculating, but based on the names... is there a common `Person` interface?

Comment: @infgeoax - Root class called object? I do believe there was mention of that such our personTest is the top, and personLocation inherits from personTest and personData would inherit from both personTest and personLocation. Do I understand that right?

Comment: @Elliot Frisch - No I don't believe there is a interface for this one, though I could be wrong, I am trying to understand polymorphism, but in the lab itself there is no mention of an interface, I believe that is in the next lab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your instructor is looking to have all of the objects in the SAME array, then you would need to rely on the fact that all objects in Java extend a super object called "Object". So, in this case, you can create a new array of type "Object", in which you can mix and match the objects that you put in it (putting both data and locations in it). Then, when you are looping through the array, you can use the java keyword "instanceof", to check if it is either  a PersonLocation or a PersonData. An example I wrote is shown here:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    PersonLocation pl1 = new PersonLocation();
    PersonLocation pl2 = new PersonLocation();
    PersonData pd1 = new PersonData();
    PersonData pd2 = new PersonData();

    Object[] array = new Object[4];
    array[0] = pl1;
    array[1] = pd1;
    array[2] = pl2;
    array[3] = pd2;

    for(Object o : array){
        if(o instanceof PersonLocation){
            PersonLocation tempPersonLocation = (PersonLocation) o;
            System.out.println(tempPersonLocation);
        }
        if(o instanceof PersonData){
            PersonData tempPersonData = (PersonData) o;
            System.out.println(tempPersonData);
        }
    }


}
```

Which gave me the output:

```
This is PersonLocation
This is PersonData
This is PersonLocation
This is PersonData
```

If you have a common interface or super class (such as PersonData inherits Person or PersonData extends Person), you could use this super class to create a single array such as the first example as well. Just change the type of the array from "Object" to whatever your interface/super class is.

It is also worth noting, that in your example where you create two arrays (one for each object type), there is no need to instantiate with size of 4 in each array, since you only have 2 of each type of objects. Instead you can instantiate with size 2, and this would result in 4 objects total, not the 8 that you had previously mentioned. An example of which is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    PersonLocation pl1 = new PersonLocation();
    PersonLocation pl2 = new PersonLocation();
    PersonData pd1 = new PersonData();
    PersonData pd2 = new PersonData();

    PersonLocation[] personLocation = new PersonLocation[2];
    PersonData[] personData = new PersonData[2];

    personLocation[0] = pl1;
    personLocation[1] = pl2;
    personData[0] = pd1;
    personData[1] = pd2;

    for (PersonLocation pl : personLocation) {
        System.out.println(pl);
    }

    for (PersonData pd : personData) {
        System.out.println(pd);
    }

}
```

Resulting in the output of:

```
This is PersonLocation
This is PersonLocation
This is PersonData
This is PersonData
```

My guess is that if your instructor has not taught you about super classes or the instanceof keyword, he is looking for something like the second example that I have showed.

Comment: That looks great, thank you so much for the explanation. I will read up on that "object" instantiation also, as well as instanceOf. Also thank you for taking the time for the outputs as well.

Comment: Glad that I could help you!